# How to evaluate when two DateTimes are equal to one another

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

This is the situation: I have a TimePicker in my application. I would like the user to be able select a time with the TimePicker, then the app will send the user a notification at the time entered with the TimePicker. I'm writing an application for Windows Phone in C#. So far, this is my code (I don't that any of this is correct)

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime? get = timePicker1.Value;         

if (now == get)
{
    ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
    toast.Title = "Title";
    toast.Content = "The Time Has Come!";
    toast.Show();
}
```

But every time I run the code, it either gives me an exception, the app doesn't load at all, and every time the notification (toast) never shows. (I also know that the app cannot be running in the foreground for the notification to show). (I know that the notification works because I can get it to work with other situations).

Basically, my questions is: how can I trigger a notification at a specific time defined by the end user?

Comment: what exception does it throw?

Comment: You don't need the "I'm sorry" parts in the question, everyone knows that learning is tough. Please tell us about the exception that is being thrown, and the reason why you used `DateTime? get` instead of `DateTime get` (i.e. why is `get` a nullable?)

Comment: Actually I don't get exceptions anymore but "get" is a nullable because you have to use a nullable with a timepicker.

Comment: The DateTime get value is nullable because most of the newer WPF controls return a nullable value instead of their non-nullable counterparts.

Comment: Basically, my questions is: how can I trigger a notification at a specific time defined by the end user?

Comment: Seems like you need a `Timer`, or some equivalent.  Not being a winphone designer I couldn't say what the specific appropriate mechanism is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the Toast notification won't show up if the app is running in foreground. It should be only used in background agents or when application is running under lock screen.
Second, if your goal is to show the notification in selected time of day, then you must not compare the DateTime values, but rather the TimeOfDay part. Also make sure user has entered valid value by checking the "get.HasValue"

Comment: Thanks! I used the TimeofDay part and I got it. I also learned from all the other answers!

Answer (score 1):

```
Line 1 : DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Line 2 : DateTime? get = timePicker1.Value;
```

in `Line 1` , you get the system current date-time, "now" is date-time and not null.
but in `Line 2`, "get" is null-able variable and you are getting the timepicker.value and compare date-time with time.
i do not know what exception you have but with 2 extra checking you can have more safe code

1. null checking for "get"
2. make sure that in your development environment you can compare date-time with time value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that `Date.Now` has a full time AND DATE!

So comparing to the `get` variable you must ignore the Date part, or probably will not work.

Try changing your `if` to look something like this:

```
if (get.HasValue && now.TimeOfDay == get.Value.TimeOfDay)
{
    // your remaining code
}
```

Also, the ShellToast class only works with background services, not on foreground apps (check the Remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltoast%28v=vs.105%29.aspx))!

If you want to show a Toast in your app, use the Toast Prompt from [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is that with an if statement, if the statement is not true, it moves one to the next block of code, and never gives a notification when the two datetimes are actually equal to eachother, since it already went through the if part

Comment: I improved my reply, please check it now

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the day, month, year values of the two DateTimes. Take minutes and seconds in account, if you want to be more precise (because I don't know on what detail level you want to compare the values).

If you want to be notified at a specific time, try [using the Alarm class](http://debugmode.net/2012/01/16/creating-alarm-and-reminder-in-windows-phone/).